# ComboBox in UserControl. setup the data binding

Tags: c#, data-binding, user-controls, combobox, windows-forms-designer

I have a combobox in a user control and i want to data bind it but the only things i have access to in the properties menu of the visual studio 2008 designer view is the data source and display member. Is there a way to setup the usercontrol so i can edit the selected value member in the properties menu too?

```
[System.ComponentModel.ComplexBindingProperties("DataSource", "DisplayMember")]
public partial class CustomComboBox : UserControl
{
    private object dataSource;
    private string displayMember;


    [AttributeProvider(typeof(IListSource))]
    public object DataSource
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dataSource;
        }

        set
        {
            this.dataSource = value;
        }
    }

    public String DisplayMember
    {
        get
        {
            return this.displayMember;
        }

        set
        {
            this.displayMember = value;
        }
    }

    public CustomComboBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BindComboBox()
    {
        if (this.dataSource == null || this.displayMember == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Binding binding = new Binding("DataSource", this.dataSource, this.displayMember, true);
        Binding binding2 = new Binding("DisplayMember", this.dataSource, this.displayMember, true);
        this.comboBox1.DataBindings.Clear();
        this.comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(binding);
        this.comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(binding2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a property for every field i wanted to edit and added [Browsable(true)] above all the properties. This let me edit everything as a text field in the properties menu.